# How do I search by "sender" or "from" in my Inbox

Tags: lotus-notes

I get tons of email (> 1 per minute) and often I know "who" sent me the email but not when so when I want to find an email I have to "sort" my entire Inbox by sender and then start scrolling through the emails from that person.  In the "form" search there is the ability to search by field but I cannot find the right field/parameters to search.  For instance here is an example of the following fields:

- DisplayFrom is "CN=John Doe/O=ACME"
- DisplaySent is "CN=John Doe/O=ACME"
- From is "CN=John Doe/O=ACME"
- INetFrom is "John_Doe@acme.com"

So if I select any of these fields in the "Search in View" area of the Inbox and enter "field DisplayFrom contains Doe" it does not match anything.

Anyone have any ideas on how to do this with Sender/From.  It seems to work with Subject but that's not a common use case for me.

Yes, sorry should have posted Lotus Notes version ... Release 8.5.3 on Linux 32 (but I've tested it on Win32 as well and fails there too).

Comment: This is really not a programming question, so it belongs on SuperUser instead of StackOverflow.  You should also specify what version of Lotus Notes (and of the Domino server, if you know it) you are asking about.  However, I will note that from a programming perspective, by searching for 'DisplayFrom' you are trying to search for what is called a computed-for-display field.  This type of field is not searchable because it exists only in memory, and only when you open the message to view it. The underlying searchable stored field, as Per Henrik noted, is called 'From'.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz It maybe that the question doesn't belong here, but the version of Domino server is not so important, or is it?

Comment: The server version *could* be important w/r/t the fields that are available for searching. Although actually, that would depend on the version of Domino that was running when the mail was actually received, not on the current version that is running.

Answer (score 1):

`field From contains SenderName` works for me and returns results (using a real name instead of `SenderName`, of course):

[image]

You can create a view based on All Documents that is categorized on sender. Perhaps this can make it easier for you to find your emails from a specific person.

Comment: This works perfectly fine for Internet style from addresses: "John Doe" <John_Doe@acme.com> but seems to fail for Internal style email addresses.  I assumed it was because of the special chars.  It does work for Internal messages sometimes but it will match 1/2 out of 10 messages from that individual (I'm not sure why this happens).